# jquery loop over object returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Tags: jquery, json, object, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have a json object which is returned as follows;

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "mapdata": [
      {
        "name": "Test title",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "lat": "51.297387",
        "lng": "-0.737240"
      }
      {
        "name": "Example Event 5",
        "description": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget tincidunt turpis. Nam tincidunt non diam eu mollis. Suspendisse lobortis rhoncus ante at auctor.&nbsp;</p>\r\n",
        "lat": "51.5232032",
        "lng": "-0.6053448999999773"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to loop over the the data array but I'm not sure how, this is the code I have so far:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/googlemaps',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        for (var key in response.data) {
            console.log(key.name);
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(key.lat, key.lng);

            // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: data.name
            });
            //send details to infoBox function to create infoWindow
            infoBox(map, marker, data);
        } // end for

    } //end success
})
```

However the when I loop over the keys and try to pass the lat and lng to the google maps function it outputs this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`

and the `console.log` is undefined for `console.log(key.name);`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how I can loop through the mapdata array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to loop through an object(response.data) instead of the array (response.data.mapdata). Also, I used the normal for loop for it. So I believe this should work:

```
for(var i = 0; i < object.data.mapdata.length; i++) {
    console.log(object.data.mapdata[i].name);
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(object.data.mapdata[i].lat, object.data.mapdata[i].lng);

    // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        title: object.data.mapdata[i].name
    });
    //send details to infoBox function to create infoWindow
    infoBox(map, marker, data);
} // end for
```

Comment: thats coming out as null

Comment: if i console.log the key it outputs `0`

Answer (score 1):

Everything is good. I just want to show you the Looping part:

```
var mapdata = response.data.mapdata;
$.each(mapdata, function(index, mapinfo){
    // Here you can find all your variables...
    console.log(mapinfo.name);
    console.log(mapinfo.lat);
    console.log(mapinfo.lng);
});
```

Hope this helps... But what I would have done if I were you is:

```
if(response.status == 'ok') {
    if (response.data.mapdata.length > 0) {
        // Here the above code of mine will go..
    } else {
        // There is no map data to display.
    }
} else {
    // Do something to notify that there is an error in the response
}
```

Comment: thanks that outputted the data in the console but didn't actually plot the pins but I like the other snippet so +1